# How to right align numbers from an array in php?

Tags: php

I have a problem with aligning numbers from a multidimensional array. I want to print the following result:

```
 1   2   3   4
12  13  14   5
11  16  15   6
10   9   8   7
```

And I want all of the numbers to be aligned with the second digit of the next rows. However my result is that:

```
1 2 3 4 
12 13 14 5 
11 16 15 6 
10 9 8 7
```

I did this in C# by using:

```
for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
{
    Console.Write("{0,4}", matrix[row, col]);
}
```

But how can I receive this result in PHP?

Comment: You could use `table` for this.

Comment: What's your mode of output? Is it stdout or HTML?

Comment: It is HTML. Isn't there any function for String Format without using `table` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);
$test = '';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    if ($key % 4 == 0) {
        $test .= "\n";
    }

    $test .= str_pad($value, 4, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo "<pre>$test</pre>";
```

The result would be:

```
   1   2   3   4
   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use ``printf``? Is ``printf('%4d', $value);`` in PHP not the equivalent of ``Console.Write("{0,4}", matrix[row, col]);`` in C#?